# How to return jsp from ajax call?

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc

I am using spring mvc without annotations.
I want to take jsp(html code) as response from ajax call.
I do not want to use **response.getWriter().print(..)**. can any one tell me any other solution.?

Comment: Why do you want JSP to be returned in AJAX. Why response.getWriter().print(..)

Comment: Need to type all code and If i change something in jsp  then that change need to do in java method also.

Comment: Why don't you send JSON back and update JSP. Thats much clean and fast. Can you show your code.

Comment: Yes. I can use it. For curiosity, I want to know is there any other way to return jsp from ajax.?

Comment: Yes. There is a way. Just return ModelAndView. `public ModelAndView blah(....)`. Populate ModelAndView with jsp path.

Answer (score 1):

You can return JSP using ModelAndView like this

```
@RequestMapping (
        value = "/path/call",
        method = RequestMethod.POST
)
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView blah(....) {
    return new ModelAndView("location to JSP file");
}
```

You could add data to MandV using the method below

```
/**
 * Add an attribute to the model.
 * @param attributeName name of the object to add to the model
 * @param attributeValue object to add to the model (never {@code null})
 * @see ModelMap#addAttribute(String, Object)
 * @see #getModelMap()
 */
public ModelAndView addObject(String attributeName, Object attributeValue) {
    getModelMap().addAttribute(attributeName, attributeValue);
    return this;
}
```

Comment: even `ModelAndView` is completely unnecessary, `String` is enough to let spring resolve your JSP - thats in fact the preferred, standard way to resolve views in spring. Am i literally the only person on the planet who read the documentation?

Comment: It completely depends on the requirement. If you need to pass some other data along then you need MandV. :)

Comment: .... no. There is no other "data" - the internal spring handlers expect a limited set of return values : http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-return-types
You cant "pass data along" - these are RETURN VALUES, you may return payload between REDIRECTS, though (via FlashMap)

Comment: setting VALUES for the MODEL has nothing to do with "passing data". I think you need to investigate the whole MVC-concept.

Answer (score 0):

i highly recommend reading [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html), without actual knowledge of the spring framework you will have a hard time using it ... As has already been mentioned, you will usually have a `Controller` class which handles `requests` - these are annotated with `@RequestMapping` and the controller is annotated with `@Controller`, of course. This is an example from the documentation :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/appointments")
public class AppointmentsController {

    private final AppointmentBook appointmentBook;

    @Autowired
    public AppointmentsController(AppointmentBook appointmentBook) {
        this.appointmentBook = appointmentBook;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Map<String, Appointment> get() {
        return appointmentBook.getAppointmentsForToday();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/{day}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Map<String, Appointment> getForDay(@PathVariable @DateTimeFormat(iso=ISO.DATE) Date day, Model model) {
        return appointmentBook.getAppointmentsForDay(day);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public AppointmentForm getNewForm() {
        return new AppointmentForm();
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String add(@Valid AppointmentForm appointment, BindingResult result) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "appointments/new";
        }
        appointmentBook.addAppointment(appointment);
        return "redirect:/appointments";
    }
}
```

As you can see, requests are now semi-automatically resolved / passed to JSP-parsers which process your stored JSP and output HTML. That is called `MVC` and although the MVC-model in spring differs a bit from the standard point of view its quite useful and somewhat standard'ish.

Yet again : if you want to use spring, **please** read the documentation. It is important and useful.

> spring mvc without annotations

pretty much defeats the whole concept. I think you need to re-do your application design, apparently it is flawed --- no offense, im just stating the obvious.